# How to minifize external CSS and JS in Wordpress (frontend)

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've integrated a external `custom.css` (*wp_enqueue_style*) and a external `custom.js` (*wp_enqueue_script*) in wordpress.

I want to minifize these scripts only for frontend. Maybe there is a plugin or something? No online minifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BWP Minify is a good option. Otherwise you'll have to roll your own.